# Relaunch Input Box

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet than when its first opened it asks the user to enter a date into the input box and it places it into a cell in the sheet. I have an error handle to pop up an invalid date error box if someone puts in the wrong date. But what I want to do is when an invalid date is entered the original input box for the date pops up again so they can reenter again. I have the code below of what I have written so far but I keep getting an error.

Thanks

```
ReShowInputBox: cellvalue = Application.InputBox("Please Enter The Date for Data Extracted (dd/mm/yyyy)")
On Error GoTo ErrHandle

ErrHandle:
MsgBox ("Invalid Date")
ReShowInputBox: cellvalue = Application.InputBox("Please Enter The Date for Data Extracted (dd/mm/yyyy)")

If cellvalue = "" Then Exit Sub
ws.Select
ws.Range("A1").Value = DateValue(cellvalue)
MsgBox ("Date Entered!")
```

Comment: Usually one would have and `Exit Sub` before the error handler.
Maybe try putting your error handler at the end of the code. If you don't exit the sub before the error handler, the code will go through those lines of code as well.

Comment: Ok so an exit sub after the last message box?

Comment: You could also look into using a Calendar Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple `Do Until` Loop:

```
Dim cellvalue As Variant

Do

    cellvalue = Application.InputBox("Please Enter The Date for Data Extracted (dd/mm/yyyy)")

Loop Until IsDate(cellvalue) And IsNumeric(Right(cellvalue, 4)) And IsNumeric(Left(cellvalue, 2)) And IsNumeric(Mid(cellvalue, 4,2))

ws.Range("A1").Value = cellvalue
MsgBox ("Date Entered!")
```

I tested this pretty thoroughly and it only accepted dates in the exact format you desire.

Comment: I tried this and no matter if the format is wrong it still works I need it to stop if the formatting is incorrect

Comment: @BriannaCates - can you explain with an example about the "format being wrong"?

Comment: When I typed in the date like 02/14/2 it still went through.. I want it to stop if its not exactly like dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @BriannaCates I think my edits have you covered now, even if it a bit clunky.

Comment: I tried that and when I put the date like 03/14/2016 it will not accept it

Comment: @BriannaCates - sorry. I messed up on the `Mid` formula. Try it now.

Comment: well crap I'm stuck in a loop now... I dont know how to break it

Comment: @BriannaCates `Ctrl + Pause` to break the code :) always best to debug step-by-step when testing :)

Comment: @BriannaCates - yw. sorry for all the back and forth with simple mistakes :(

Comment: No worries what you did was perfect! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to repeatedly ask for a date until you get one, but allow the user to cancel out:

```
Sub fhskjfs()
    Dim i As String, d As Date
    i = ""

    While Not IsDate(i)
        i = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a date", Type:=2)
        If i = False Then Exit Sub
        If IsDate(i) Then d = CDate(i)
    Wend
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a way to implement a simple format check:

```
Public Function CheckFormat(i As String) As String
    CheckFormat = "junk"
    ary = Split(i, "/")
    If UBound(ary) <> 2 Then Exit Function
    If CLng(ary(2)) < 1900 Or CLng(ary(2)) > 9999 Then Exit Function
    If CLng(ary(1)) > 12 Then Exit Function
    If CLng(ary(0)) > 31 Then Exit Function
    CheckFormat = i
End Function

Sub GetDate()
    Dim i As String, d As Date
    i = ""

    While Not IsDate(i)
        i = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a date", Type:=2)
        If i = "False" Then Exit Sub
        i = CheckFormat(i)
        If IsDate(i) Then d = CDate(i)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way I can have this set to only accept a certain format?

Comment: Just to add one detail, this particular method is giving you a variable of type Date, which you can then format to display with whatever date format you like, i.e. Format(d, "dd/mm/yyyy").  As such, it doesn't require the user to follow the strict format rules to enter the date (they can use anything that VBA recognizes as a date), but you can still put it into the format you need.  This might be a bit easier for the end user, depending on your specific situation.

Comment: @BriannaCates  See my **EDIT#1**